# Article stock transaction table query Max Date gives multiple results on same timestamp, only need the last

Tags: mysql, unique, stock, maxdate

I've got an Article Stock transaction table, I only need the columns: Article, Date and Stock.

On the Same day, even on the same timestamp the table gives me multiple results for the same article, I only need the article with the latest date. It seems that the last in row is the article with the most recent Stock value. Bud how can I write this in a query that it only shows me the latest Date? (Blue row in Screenshot)

In my example I filtered it on only one article.

```
 SELECT artikel as Article, max(datum) as `Date`, bestand as 
 Stock  FROM data.HB001ARTIKELBESTANDSBEWEGUNG
 where datum > "2021-08-11 00:00:00" and datum < "2021-08-13 
00:00:00" and lager = 1 and artikel = '5201114970'
group by artikel, bestand, datum
order by artikel;
```

[image: Result Query]

With kind regards,

Björn

I added the extra row with the auto increment, so now I get for every article with the latest date the highest row number. How can I filter now that i only get one result per article?

```
SELECT Article, max(CountDate), Stock, Nr  FROM data.STOCKCOUNT
where CountDate > "2021-08-11 00:00:00"  and CountDate < "2021- 
08-13 00:00:00" and Article IN ('5201114970', '1361001580')
group by Article, Stock, CountDate, Nr
order by Nr, CountDate desc, Article;
```

[image]
[image]

I added the extra row with the auto increment, so now I get for every article with the latest date the highest row number. How can I filter now that i only get one result per article filtered on the highest row number per article?

```
SELECT artikel as Article, max(datum) as Date, bestand as Stock, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY datum asc) as Nr  FROM 
data.HB001ARTIKELBESTANDSBEWEGUNG b where datum > "2021-08-11 
00:00:00" and datum < "2021-08-13 00:00:00" and lager = 1 and 
artikel in ('5201114970', '1361001580') group by artikel, 
bestand, datum order by datum desc, artikel
```

[image]

Comment: I think there is no logic to pick  latest date because all the date values are same. You need to modify your insert query or else add a auto increment column to the table and pick the max auto incremented value for a specific date

Comment: Thank you Rosh for the reply, I know it looks like it makes no sense, but I checked several articles, and always the last is the one with the correct stock value. Is there some kind of time stamp beneath the surface that contains even a more specific timestamp, maybe in milliseconds? I will try out the idea with the auto increment column.

Comment: change column type to timestamp(3) and insert record using  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) to include milliseconds to your records. tested with mysql 5.7

Comment: @rosh-dev could you tell me how to filter on the highest row number, see my answer. The timestamp gives :000 milliseconds, so I unfortunately I can't use it.

Comment: @rosh-dev I added the information to the question.

Comment: I meant an auto increment column to the table. not in the query.

Comment: @rosh-dev Ok, I deleted the row in the query and added an auto increment to the table.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the query. I can't test

```
SELECT Article, max(Nr), Stock, CountDate  FROM data.STOCKCOUNT
where CountDate > "2021-08-11 00:00:00"  and CountDate < "2021- 
08-13 00:00:00" and Article IN ('5201114970', '1361001580')
group by Article, Stock, CountDate
order by Nr DESC;
```

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding, because now I get the same list but in reverse. 
I need from every article only one result. 

With the auto increment row it did something good, every article it started new from 1 till the end of that article range. The correct value was always the last number in that range, so when I could filter on every article and then the highest auto increment number per article, that would give mem the correct result and for every article a single value.

Comment: My answer will not work if you run that for multiple articles and I thought you will run this query only for one article.

Comment: I added new information in my question, I used the ROW_NUMBER in de the query, is there a way to filter per article on the highest row number? Because then I have my result.

Comment: I don't recommend ROW_NUMBER solution. Your records order not guaranteed